# How to migrate existing choice columns (containing data) to Managed MetaData columns using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, managed-metadata

I have 5 choice columns on a SharePoint library, containing ~1000 rows. I would like to migrate these 5 columns into Managed Metadata fields and maintain the data. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The steps are quite straight forward:

1. Create the managed metadata columns
2. Map the data from the choice columns to the managed meta data columns (the powershell part, basically one loop)
3. Verify that everything is correct
4. Delete the old columns

Comment: Item number 2 is specifically what my question is regarding. Do you happen to have any resources or places to start?