# SharePoint Online: How to import values into a managed metadata column?

Tags: sharepoint-online, managed-metadata

Is it possibly to copy/migrate values into a managed metadata column?  Everything I'm reading either pertains to SharePoint OnPrem, or copying/migrating taxonomy (groups and sets) - neither of which apply.

I have a choice column that contains values.  We've since begun to use the Term Store.  Now that I've created a managed metadata column pointing to the appropriate term set, how can I move existing values from the previous column to this new managed metadata column?

This won't be a one-time-only task.  We have numerous opportunities to begin using the Term Store, if I can copy existing values to the new columns.

Thank you!

Comment: Did you ever figure out a solution?   I'm considering doing the same but when I try and copy across a `Single` or `Multi` selection from a `Choice` column to a `Managed Metadata` column in Grid view in a Document Library, I get error:  `The data returned from the tagging UI was not formatted correctly`.  Also, just for reference, I notice when I export these document libraries from SharePoint online - Choice column outputs values like `Option01;#Option02` whereas Managed Metadata column outputs values like `47;#Option01;#48;#Option02`.  I have not yet figured out what the numbers represent.

Comment: For reference, seems there are existing answers [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/272353/need-help-sharepoint-online-powershell-to-copy-choice-to-managed-metadata-column) and [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/61998/how-to-migrate-existing-choice-columns-containing-data-to-managed-metadata-col) - but i don't have PowerShell access where I am.